# Install fluentd on openshift without elastic search?

Tags: openshift, syslog, fluentd

On openshift 4. 3, will config fluentd to forward logs to external syslog. Could I install fluentd only without install elasticsearch etc?

Thanks

Weiren

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install only fluentd by only specifying the `collection` part when deploying the `ClusterLogging` CRD:

```
apiVersion: logging.openshift.io/v1
kind: ClusterLogging
metadata:
  name: instance
  namespace: openshift-logging
spec:
  collection:
    logs:
      fluentd: {}
      type: fluentd
  managementState: Managed
```

Note that later versions of OpenShift even allow you to specify `LogForwarding`. More information on how to deploy the ClusterLogging can be found in the documentation: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/logging/cluster-logging-deploying.html#cluster-logging-deploy-clo-cli_cluster-logging-deploying

Comment: Hit error, any idea?

 
$ oc create -f clo-instance.yaml
error: unable to recognize "clo-instance.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterLogging" in version "logging.openshift.io/v1"
$

Comment: Looks like the Cluster Logging Operator was not installed properly, re-check the steps in the documentation on how to install it.

Comment: Indeed. But with proper installation of EFK, if I only specify fluentd in CR, fluentd does not start. The CR seems have to include all other sections in addition to "collection". Is there any way preventing fluentd sending logs to elasticsearch?